# Json 404 in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, json, web-services, symfony-1.4

I am building a json api. Formats are managed nicely via the routing.yml configuration file:

```
user_info:
  url: /users/:user_id
  class: sfRequestRoute
  param: { module: user, action: details, sf_format: json }
  requirements:
    user_id: \d+
    sf_method: [GET]
```

Now I would like to make sure that any request that is sent to my app will return a result in json format (example: "/dummy" should return an error in json). I am getting on track with the following default route at the end of the same file:

```
default:
  url: /*
  param: { sf_format: json }
```

When I route to an inexisting page or module, this renders correctly a json... Error! The html page generated was a 404, now with this routing I get a 500 (server error). How can I keep a similar behaviour as the one I had in the default html page, just changing the rendering into a json output?

### EDIT - following 1Ed instructions

So I edited my factories.yml, created a default module in my api project, there in my default actions added the executeError404 function mentioned below... Then I Set up the corresponding Error404Success.php page...

For some reason, I still need the routes, which I modified to avoid the :module and :action keywords:

```
default_index:
  url:   /:a

default:
  url: /:a/:b/*
```

And here there I am ! My 404 page comes in json format for the whole api :)
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This default route will execute the `index` action of the `default` module (by default). You should add a `indexSuccess.json.php` template file to the default module or modify the `default/index` action to return a json response early.

If you just want to return a 404 every time if this default route matches you can change the default action to `error404` in `factories.yml`:

```
all:
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
      default_action:                   error404
```

Or you can set the request format of the default 404 action explicitly to json like this

```
public function executeError404(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $request->setRequestFormat('json');
}
```

and you can remove the default route.

I recommend **NOT to use** these kind of default routes as they make really hard to keep track of all possible URL-s to the site.
You should create a separate route for each particular action or use route collections.

Comment: Thanks for the details - I could get it on track !